# Convergence of $a_n = n|\sin n|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the convergence of the following sequence? 
$$a_n=n|\sin n|$$
I looked on Wolfram and it doesn't go to infinity. Also I was told to use Louville's theorem but..., I found many theorems with that name...

Comment: This sequence has no limit, but I don't see how Liouville's theorem would help.

Comment: I'd rather say Weyl's equidistribution theorem and Lagrange's theorem on continued fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply does not converge. Since $\pi$ is an irrational number, the sequence $\{e^{in}\}_{n\geq 0}$ is dense in the unit circle (equidistributed, actually), hence $\{|\sin n|\}_{n\geq 0}$ is dense in $[0,1]$ and 
$$\limsup_{n\to +\infty} n|\sin n|=+\infty.$$
On the other hand, such sequence has a finite $\liminf$. Let $\frac{p}{q}$ be a convergent of the continued fraction of $\pi$: then $|p-q\pi|\leq\frac{1}{q}$, hence $\sin(p)$ is at most $\frac{1}{q}$ apart from zero and $p|\sin p|$ is at most $\pi+\frac{1}{q^2}\leq \pi+1$.

Answer (score 0):

By the Dirichlet's approximation theorem, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $p$ and $q\leq n$ such that $|2\pi-\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{nq}$. Then, $p|\sin(p)|\leq p|p-q\cdot 2\pi|+p\cdot o(p-q\cdot 2\pi)\leq \frac{2}{q}$

Comment: I have already written that and this just proves the $\liminf$ is finite. But all right, that is the only non-trivial part, probably.

Comment: yeah, when i post the solution i see your's hahah

Comment: i take it from https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_de_aproximaci%C3%B3n_de_Dirichlet u.u